# Ruby on Rails - show_user_path NoMethodError in Users#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a begginer in Rails, im following code from a book and i am trying stuff to see if it breaks/works, anyway heres my UserControllers classUserController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

 def new
   @user = User.new
 end

 def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end

 def show
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end

 def create
   @user = User.new(params[:user])
   if @user.save
      redirect_to @user, :notice => 'Cadastro realizado'

   else
     render :new
   end
  end      
end
```

And heres my show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%=notice%></p>

<h2>Perfil: <%=@user.full_name %></h2>

    <ul>
        <li>Localização: <%= @user.location %> </li>
        <li>Bio: <%= @user.bio %></li>
   </ul>

   <%= link_to 'Editar Perfil', edit_user_path(@user) %>
   <%= link_to 'Mostrar Perfil', show_user_path(@user) %>
```

My problem is in the last line, when i try to acess this page i get a NomethodError,i am trying to understand **why**, why can i just change that to @user and the page works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
 <%= link_to 'Mostrar Perfil', user_path(@user) %>
```

or even just

```
 <%= link_to 'Mostrar Perfil', @user %>
```

In order to see how to name the routes, open a console and run

```
rake routes
```

Comment: I tried the last line and it worked fine, i just didnt knew why, doenst make more sense to be like : method_user_path ?

Comment: See section 2.2 and 2.3 of the Rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html